# Showing configuration options depending on users access to bundle

Tags: symfony, hook, bundles

I am creating an app that will be extended by several bundles. Users will have access to different bundles based on roles. Some of these bundles will have configuration options, and I want one page with all config forms.

What I want to do is create a page that every bundle will "hook" into, and show the configuration form if the bundle has one.

There will also be a dashboard page that each bundle should "hook" into and show a dashboard widget.

Is there any way of achieving this in symfony? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood the [The DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)  so I guess the answer lies there. In detail, I will try to create an event in the configuration controller, and all bundles will have a subscriber to this event, and somehow have the forms available for the configuration twig file. But that is another question.